# apollographql useMutation 'variables:' param can't read state variable/s

Tags: variables, apollo-client, setstate

**First, a description, then some code:**

I'm trying to push myself, to better understand how to use ApolloGraphQL. At this point I want to create variables for a mutation on-the-fly, but don't see how to make it work.

For this project, useMutation and all of the related code works when literal values are assigned the 'variables:' option of the useMutation call, ie hard-coded. So I know that the useMutation call / related code is working.

The problem happens when trying to assign State variables to the 'variables:' option in useMutation. The State variables are valid, meaning they are in the same shape as the hard-coded versions that work. I just can't figure out how to turn the State variable into something that works inside of useMutation.

**Here is some code:**

```
    export function Table(props) {
       const [vars, setVars] = useState({}) 
       // example vars: {customerId: 1, firstName: 'first name'}, but could be other things

       console.log('before updateField vars ', vars) // 'vars' correctly shown
    
       const [ updateField ] = useMutation(UPDATE_POLICY_FIELD, {
        variables: vars, //<--- it's broken here. but, shows value of 'vars' in onError

        onError: error => {     
            console.log('onError vars ', vars)  // 'vars' correctly shown
            console.log('Error ' , error)
        },
       });

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("useEffect vars ", vars)  // 'vars' correctly shown
        updateField()
     }, [vars])

   // an example vars after setVars: {customerId: 1, firstName: 'firstName'}. This works.
   setVars(`{customerId: ${row.original.customerId}, ${column.id}: ${e.target.value }}`)

 } // end export function Table
```

I've tried everything I can think of, but every attempted solution fails at the

variables: var

part.

What I'm looking for is something like:
variables: {customerId: 1, firstName: 'firstName'}
in the useMutation code block.

Hopefully this is something simple, and I just don't see it yet. Any help / advice for how to get 'variables: vars' to work is really appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that 'vars' was of type String, created that way in setVars()

Making an object fixed it. Like so:

```
setVars({
                    customerId: parseInt(row.original.customerId, 10),
                    [column.id]: e.target.value
                })
```

I knew it had to be something simple. Leaving this post up in case it helps others.

Thank you for your time and attention.